# Base64.encode() not working for large byte array

Tags: java, base64, encode

This line of code seems stop working when size of input byte array is too large:

```
byte[] encoded = Base64.encode(content, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

where the input is: `byte[] content` which is very large.

Is there anyway to get around this large size problem.

Thanks in advance!

Shawn

Comment: What do you mean with "stops working"? Does it throw an error? Does it hang? How large must the array be? Also, what library does the `Base64` class come from? It does not look like the standard Java API.

Comment: This looks like `android.util.Base64`, in which case you should use [android.util.Base64OutputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64OutputStream) to encode large amounts of data

Comment: @thatotherguy, can you please provide some example?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know enough about the Android API, so someone else should feel free. Using Base64OutputStream is easy, the tricky part is rewriting the program to allow using `Input/OutputStream` instead of `byte[]` for whatever your particular data source/sink is

Answer (score 1):

Instead of [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html), you can use [Base64InputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64InputStream.html) which provides Base64 encoding and decoding in a streaming fashion (unlimited size). You can check [this](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64InputStream) for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information provided, the only thing I can think to suggest is to break up the `content` array into smaller chunks and iterate through them.

Comment: Not sure how to do this. divide the byte array in chuck, say, the length is N, how many chunk would be divided to guarantee encode() work? Also as I am aware of, when encoding, there will be some size inflation in the encoded string, can we simply append those encoded strings from the chunks of the byte array, will the appended string be the same as the string encoded from the original byte array at all?